# SshNet - Catch Exception and show a message

Tags: c#, ssh

I'm using sshNet to develop a little program that connects to a Linux server via SSH.

It works fine, but when the user or pass is wrong it throws a default exception message and I want to catch the exception and show a MessageBox with an specific text.

Code:

```
public void comandoSSH(string comando)
    {
        using (var ssh = new SshClient(ip, user, pass))
        {

            try
            {
                ssh.Connect();
                var responseSsh = ssh.RunCommand(comando);
                var response = responseSsh.Result;
                ssh.Disconnect();
                Output(response);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                "My Text",
                "Warning!",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work, it just shows the default message.

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: You want to show Exception's message in your MessageBox?

Comment: What doesn't work? Doesn't the messagebox appear? You aren't displaying the exception anyway, just `My Text`. Have you checked the [Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) class's properties? You can get the short exception message with `Exception.Message` or the full exception with `Exception.ToString()`